# Settings > Language & input > Pointer speed - why do we need this menu?

Tags: android, mouse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, trackpad

I am using ICS android phone.
I can see **pointer speed** menu, at `Settings > Language & input > MOUSE/TRACKPAD.`

Is this menu necessary?
why do we need this menu?

Answer (score 4):

There are tablets such as the Asus Transformer, operate in dual mode (as a tablet and like a latop when docked). In the docked mode, they display a mouse pointer similar to a laptop and are controlled by a Trackpad. This menu is for controlling the sensitivity of the mouse pointer in those devices.

[image: The Transformer]

Answer (score -1):

`Pointer Speed:`

The phrase is consider as when you move your finger on the screen, how much/smooth it should move on the screen. It is same as the Mouse Pointer Movement Settings in Control Panel in Desktop Computers.